# How to create html table by reading column values from an XMLfile

Tags: java, jquery, html, xml

I have to create a table in an html file by reading column names from an XML file. I am using java, Wicket, JQuery etc..(No hard coding of column names in html file) any suggestions?

Comment: bit of a broad question there fella.

Comment: Here's a tip: look up XML manipulation in javascript (hint: it's a lot like Objects), look up jquery's .get() method, look up jquery's .append() or .html() methods. Ultimately what you're asking for isn't difficult, but it is broad. If you want a timely response, you'll need to try it yourself first and let us correct you where you went wrong. **Edit**: of course this is assuming you actually want to use jQuery. If you want to just construct the table, look up Java's XML parsing.

Comment: is XSL an option for this project?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

just grabbed from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp